# Regex throws error in Coldfusion but works in JS

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I have an email regex that I've been using in Javascript and works fine, but when I try to use it in Coldfusion I get an error.

The regex is:

```
<cfset regex = '^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#\$%&’*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)+)+$'>
```

The error I get is:

> The CFML compiler was processing:
>
> An expression beginning with /', on line 28, column 16.This message is
>   usually caused by a problem in the expressions structure. A cfset tag
>   beginning on line 28, column 2.

It seems to be complaining about the `/` but I have escaped it `\/`. Furthermore, as far as I can tell, it is not on column 16. When I add characters before or after the `/` the line number doesn't change. If I add characters to the variable name, for example, it does.

I have tried with and without escape backslashes, enclosing the regex in `/.../` and parens `(^....$)`.

The regex should match whole word a valid email address such as `sample@me.com`, `another@some.sub.net`, etc.

It will not match if there are spaces or invalid characters such as: `not@valid@email.com`, `'   toomuch@space.com  '`, or `wrong.pattern@foo`

Does anyone see where my error is?

Comment: You need to escape the hash `#` as in `'^[a-zA-Z0-9.!##\$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ColdFusion you need to escape the `#`. You can do this by adding consecutive `##`

```
<cfset regex = '^[a-zA-Z0-9.!##\$%&’*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)+)+$'>
```

Comment: Yup, that's it! I just stumbled upon it myself and was going to update :)